как с помощью views в drupal 7 вывести в title несколько терминов из разных словарей или несколько полей из ноды
Пробовал добавлять несколько контекстных фильтров, но заголовок переопределяется только для одного фильтра, а нужно иметь возможность  при отображении ноды с помощью views в заголовке показывать несколько полей.
Например во многих странах есть одинаковые названия городов, чтобы заголовки были уникальными, нужно вместо: Город Название (Страна), вывести: Город Название (Регион, Страна).
